# Getting the HTML page from my website and inject it inside my chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

i want to get the html page from link of my website and inject it like html again inside my `popup.html` page in google chrome extension 
i need the code to be by using JavaScript and  i don't want any  jquery  because 
i did part of  it before with jquery with this

```
$.get('some website ', function(data) {
  $('.result').html(data);
  alert('Load was performed.');
});
```

but i want JavaScript code to get the html from link which i want to define it inside the code

for example i have website like `www.something.com/page.html`
and i need to take the sourse code of page.html and inject it inside popup.html
that mean the extension will show me `page.html`

i hope that wanna be good explanation

Comment: Are you just looking for innerHTML?  It's a bit difficult understanding your question...

Comment: Do you want like an iframe that'll show your website in the popup, or do you want to copy the html from your website and put it in your popup?

Comment: no what i need is to get the html from page for example : www.some.com/page.html
and after that i need to post page.html inside  popup.html

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick, but be aware of the [security implications](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr#security-considerations) of injecting a bunch of HTML into another document -- it's an easy way to cause [XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)):

```
var element = ... // some element in your popup.html document
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.onload = function() {
  element.innerHTML = this.responseText;
};
request.open("get", "http://www.some.com/page.html", true);
request.send();
```

You'll also need to add a permission to your manifest to allow your extension to do cross-site XHRs to `"http://www.some.com"`. Assuming no other permissions:

```
"permissions": [
  "http://www.somecom/"
],
```

From a **security POV**, it makes more sense to just ask some.com for JSON data, parse that through `JSON.parse()` and then build whatever UI you need in the Chrome extension. Makes your extension also more stable/flexible because all UI is contained in the Chrome extension, not spread across extension and some.com.

Alternatively, if `page.html` is sufficiently static, bundle it into your extension and inject it with a code snippet similar to the one above, but use `chrome.extension.getUrl('page.html')` as the URL for `request.open()`.

Regardless of whether your `page.html` comes from another site or from within the extension, you might need to fix relative URLs of images, scripts, style sheets (Chrome won't do this for you here), e.g. by prefixing their src/href attributes with `http://www.some.com/` to point them to the intended resources again.